# C character array initialization

Tags: c, arrays, char

In the following code:

```
char *p = "Linux";
```

Is the memory for "Linux" on the stack or the read only segment of the program?

Refer to question 9 in the article [12 Interesting C Interview Questions and Answers](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-interview-questions/).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not trust that link or something?

Comment: @Pubby My instructor for C programming always says its on the stack, hence the doubt.

Comment: He's probably saying `p` (the pointer) is on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is free to store it wherever it wants. It's a constant, so it can be in read-only memory, but it is not required to be.

> My instructor for C programming always says its on the stack, hence the doubt.

He probably means the pointer. Consider:

```
char *p = "Linux";
p = "Rules";
```

In the second line, something changed from pointing to "Linux" to pointing to "Rules". That thing that just changed is on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

As the link says, it is not stored in dynamically allocated memory, rather the memory that is where the code itself lives. I.e. the read only sections. Hence the reason why trying to change it results in a segfault.